# Is the Laravel router route URL correct?

Tags: php

WelcomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

ArticlesController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return __METHOD__ . '은(는) Article 컬렉션을 조회합니다.';
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return __METHOD__ . '은(는)Article 컬렉션을 만들기 위한 폼을 담은 뷰를 반환합니다.';
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return __METHOD__ . '은(는) 사용자의 입력한 폼 데이터로 새로운 Article 컬렉션을 만듭니다.';
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(string $id)
    {
        return __METHOD__ . '은(는)다음 기본 키를 가진 Article 모델을 조회합니다.:'.$id;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(string $id)
    {
        return __METHOD__ . '은(는)다음 기본 키를 가진 Article 모델을 수정하기 위한 폼을 담은 뷰를 반환합니다.:'.$id;
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        return __METHOD__ . '은(는)사용자의 입력한 폼 데이터로 다음 기본 키를 가진 Article 모델을 수정합니다.:'.$id;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(string $id)
    {
        return __METHOD__ . '은(는)다음 기본 키를 가진 Article 모델을 삭제합니다.:'.$id;
    }
}
```

1. Enter php artisan make:controller command in visual studio code
   console
2. Create WelcomeController and ArticlesController files

web.app

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

// Route::get('/', function(){
//     return view('welcome');
// });

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::resource('articles','ArticlesController');
```

- Enter the php artisan route:list command
  [image]

I entered the command php artisan route:list in the visual studio code console in my PHP Laravel project, but an error occurred. The path seems to be the problem, I checked app/Http/Controllers to match, but it doesn't solve it.

Comment: `ArticlesController` and `WelcomeController` are in same folder?

Comment: Add this line `use App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController;` on top of web.php

Comment: The WelcomeController and ArticlesController files are located in the Controllers subfolder.

Comment: What is name of subfolder? Please edit the question and provide info about subfolder. you may need to modify namespace in controllers if there is any folder exist inside `Controllers`

Comment: I misunderstood. There is no Controllers subfolder. sorry.

Comment: Are you using laravel 8 or 8+? If yes make sure you have  `protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';` this line exist in your `RouteServiceProvider` file

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
Is there a part where I have a problem, like the grammar is wrong?

Comment: Refer my above comment, and yes controller name should be singular, It's recommended.

Comment: protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers'; I added it and ran it, but the result was not good. Any other workaround?

Comment: You could name your controller `Brombeer` if you wanted, doesn't really matter (won't throw an error) if it's singular or plural - just make it consistent

Comment: "_but the result was not good_" doesn't help us very much. Please post complete error messages. And please post (in your question) which version of Laravel you are using. You might also want to read https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers to learn more about Resource Controllers and how to use them

Comment: thank you. I applied the code by referring to the router syntax through the link you sent, and it worked. ^^

Comment: @ChaeSeongLim, you can upvote and accept the answer below, It will help other people as well!!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `web.php` file like this if you're using Laravel 8 or 8+, since this is a modern way to call controller classes in routes from laravel 8.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController; 

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

// Route::get('/', function(){
//     return view('welcome');
// });

Route::get('/', [WelcomeController::class,'index']);

Route::resource('articles',ArticlesController::class);
```

and make sure you've namespace exist in your `RouteServiceProvider` like below,

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```